# Re: The duplicate question must exist on Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

Here's a question on SQA: [What is the difference between jUnit & TestNG?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18585/what-is-the-difference-between-junit-testng) that seems a duplicate of the [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658/junit-vs-testng) with already tons of answers and many upvotes.

However, when I marked SQA question as a duplicate of the Stackoverlow question I got an error

> The duplicate question must exist on Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange.

- Should I then mark the question rather as off-topic?
- Or perhaps our forum (I consider myself as part of this community) is more about integration and end-to-end testing, while StackOverflow is more about unit testing and thus it would be better to change question to be more specific to our context, e.g. "What is the difference between jUnit & TestNG in end-to-end and integration testing?"

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, what is on or off topic on other sites are not relevant to what is on or off topic here. By the same logic, what is a duplicate only cares about what it is here on this site.

A question can be perfectly on topic on both sites and may be duplicated. In fact, one may even reference the other.